# IIS-based website with NLB and ARR

Tags: iis, arr, nlb

I have a test environment where I want to have IIS installed on 2 servers, in such a way that they host a website tied to a single IP balanced via NLB and routed via ARR.  I have the two servers with IIS 7.5 installed now.

What I am looking to do is:

1. Host a site inside of IIS using UNC (I can already host a sample site inside of `wwwroot` locally)
2. Install NLB as a cluster for both servers
3. Install ARR and add a ServerFarm in IIS for both servers

Can anyone tell me if any of this is possible?  I have looked into various pages on ServerFault, as well as here on stackoverflow, on IIS.net, on other forums, without success.  I just need a basic website that I can get hosted on an internal fileshare via UNC path.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

G

Comment: Hello G, I'm curious whether you ever got this working and what you learned from it -- did it turn out to be the optimal setup or did you find something better?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is absolutely possible, in fact there are great tutorials on doing just that:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/achieving-high-availability-and-scalability-arr-and-nlb

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/configure-3-tier-deployment-architecture-using-application-request-routing